# Why would Cornelius send back the message?

Tags: character-motivation, stephen-baxter, manifold-time

In Manifold: Time, by Stephen Baxter, why would Cornelius send back a message back in time through the blue portal to himself that identified Cruithne?  If he didn't send the message, he would never have come to Cruithne, and wouldn't be in danger of immediate death.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume Cornelius could retroactively rescue himself from his fate, then he would also prevent himself from seeing the fruition of what had become his life's work.  He would never get to explore deep time and see all the wonders beyond the blue portal.  For Cornelius the rewards were clearly worth the possible loss of his life.  Having experienced the adventure he *knew* that it was worth it, and so he transmitted the message to his past self, closing the causal loop.

Comment: He was also (canonically) on the autism spectrum - it's entirely possible that he did it as, effectively, an extremely geeky form of OCD.